# Create one to many relationship between two classes in core PHP

Tags: php, oop, php-8, php-8.1

Kindly can someone guide me on how to achieve this?

- Create a class `Company` and define attributes `Company Name`,
  `Company Address`.
- Create a class `Employees` and define attributes    `Employee Name`,
  `Phone Number`, and `Email`.
- Create a relationship    between the    above two classes where a
  `Company` can have multiple    `Employees` in    such a way as to
  retrieve company and its employee    information    through its
  `Company` object.

Comment: Learn the basics. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: Since it seems like you want to work with classes that store information, you might want to look at using Doctrine ORM. Using Doctrine to do this can help you guide yourself through this process. https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html 
I also agree with Markus that reading about the basics would be great :)

Comment: If you feel that my reply is helpful, then you can upvote or mark my reply as an answer to simplify the future search of other users. [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/309682)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create `Employee`  class:

```
class Employee 
{
    public $name
    public $phoneNumber
    public $mail
}
```

and Company class:

```
class Company 
{
    public $name;
    public $address;
    public $matchCount;
    public $employees = array();
}
```

You can use the following snippet:

```
$company = new Company();
$company->employees[0] = new Employee();
```